# Change Order of Admin Posts Depending on Meta

Tags: posts, wp-admin, order, page-attributes

In my Admin Panel I have a custom post type of posts - with page attributes to define order. Is there "easy" way of changing how the admin panel pulls posts so I can reorder them?

[Page Attributes](http://make.wordpress.org/support/user-manual/content/pages/page-attributes/#order) define order and parents. My Custom Post Type isn't a page but it still supports Page Attributes because I want to order them in a meaningful way.

Currently in Wordpress Admin Panel when using Custom Post Types and Page Attributes, the Admin Panel doesn't order posts in the defined order, it instead orders all posts by publish date (so newest on top). I'm looking to use Page Attributes to order my Custom Post Type posts in the admin panel in the same order defined by Page Attributes.

Even more clarification:

Defined in `register_post_type()` as `supports => array()` [Found Here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments)

[image: Shows where to find Page Attributes when inside Edit CPT]

The expected outcome would be something like this, where the post with page attribute 0 is at the top and the greatest page attribute would be at the bottom:

[image: Shows an example of the expected output with the Order set.]

Comment: Can you elaborate on "define order" and "reorder"?

Comment: Well right now the posts are showing up top to bottom by latest created. I want to change the order so that they're ordered by the page attribute "Order" I defined. so that 0 will be at the top and 999 will be at the bottom.

Comment: What is a "page attribute"? What is your custom post type? You're not giving enough information for somebody to give you a meaningful answer, much less code to do it.

Comment: [Page Attributes](http://make.wordpress.org/support/user-manual/content/pages/page-attributes/#order) define order and parents. My Custom Post Type isn't a page but it still supports Page Attributes because I want to order them in a meaningful way.

Comment: Making your custom post type `hierarchical` allows for this sorting natively. You'll have to do a `pre_get_posts` to change this for your list table.

Comment: Setting hierarchical will also allow parents, which posts do not need, nor do I want to give an option for.

Comment: This was just published today and looks like it covers the topic in depth: http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2013/12/05/modifying-admin-post-lists-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Post list in admin (edit.php) use a normal `WP_Query`, just like frontend can be changed using `pre_get_posts`.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'reorder_my_cpt');
    
function reorder_my_cpt( $q ) {
  if ( !is_admin() || !$q->is_main_query() ) {
    return;
  }
  $s = get_current_screen();
  // change 'book' with your real CPT name
  if ( $s->base === 'edit' && $s->post_type === 'book' ) {
    $q->set('orderby', 'menu_order');
    $q->set('order', 'ASC');
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks promising, im going to run it through a few cases! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. And glad it works.

Comment: Works in 2021! (Surprised this is not the default behaviour?!)

Comment: Important note - the code in the answer did break the frontend of the website - 'PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_current_screen()'. To fix this I just had to move the 'is_admin()' check outside the 'get_current_screen()' function.

Comment: Thanks @00-BBB, I adjusted the code.